# Navigation bar items float behind logo when resizing browser window

Tags: css, navbar

So I'm working on the website for the company I work with, and it seems like there is a functionality issue with the nav bar when the browser is resized. I've been staring at the code for this page for a few days now, and I can't seem to find where this issue is located. I inherited this page from a different developer, so I'm just trying to wrap my head around how this was all set up.

The site is https://www.apprenace.com/ and you'll notice the "About Apprenace" link will go behind the actual logo on the left side, until the browser hits the specific size to turn the nav bar into a dropdown menu. I've been trying to change the position attributes of the nav bar itself, but that didn't seem to help with anything.

Thank you in advance for any help. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Can you give a little more info? Like what tools/frameworks you are using to get that behavior?

Comment: It's a Wordpress site, and the other developer on the site was seemingly using two stylesheets for some reason, one typical css and then one sass. However, I believe the sass sheet was something he was just messing around with (I recently just found out that this website was initially just a "test" for him when he started as a dev, then the company liked it so they just went with it). Right now I just have pulled the css from the Wordpress site to try messing around. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your .mo-header-menu there are two columns, one for logo, one for menu.  I modified the existing column size classes slightly to make things fit.  The other alternative would be to adjust your bootstrap mobile SM breakpoint.

This works:

```
<div class="mo-header-menu">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mo-col-logo">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9 mo-col-menu">...</div>
</div>
```

Speaking to the comments above, you shouldn't need to edit the stylesheet, just some HTML class attributes in the header layout/theme file.

Comment: Ahh that makes so much more sense to me. I was wondering why the other dev was telling me that the issue in question was going to be in the stylesheets, but I just went with it because he actually wrote it out. Thank you for the help, I'm going to add that in now.

Comment: Yep, just added that into the php code for the headers and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also the reason there are SASS and CSS files in there, is likely because the SASS files are processed in to CSS during a build process.  You'll want to edit the SASS files, run the build, and your CSS files should reflect the changes.  If you change your CSS files, and then the SASS files get processed, your CSS changes will be overwritten so be careful!  I am unsure of how Wordpress/Wordpress themes usually implement this process though.